# Javascript dynamically add elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to dynamically add table rows using Javascript (I will add Ajax requests later on), but I'm having the following error: `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8`

My code is as follows:

```
function SplitsJob() {

var newJob = document.createElement("tr");
newJob.innerHTML = "<tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>";

var under = document.getElementById("row1");
document.body.insertBefore(newJob, under);
}
```

When this function is called, I want to add another `<tr>` (with the contents of `newJob.innerHTML`) beneath the `<tr>` with the id `row1`.

I have found the code on [this Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement)

Comment: np - are you getting any line # for your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row1"><td>xxx</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:InsertBefore();return false;">Insert Before</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:AppendChild();return false;">Append Child</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:InsertRow();return false;">InsertRow</a>
```

samle SCRIPT:

```
var i=0;
function randColor() {
    var str=Math.round(16777215*Math.random()).toString(16);
    return "#000000".substr(0,7-str.length)+str;
}

function InsertBefore() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var under = document.getElementById("row1");
    var newJob = document.createElement("tr");
    newJob.style.backgroundColor=randColor();
    //newJob.innerHTML = "<tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>"; // its inserted inside TR. no additional TR's needed.
    newJob.innerHTML = "<td>Foo "+(i++)+".</td><td>Bar</td>";
    table.tBodies[0].insertBefore(newJob,under);
}

function AppendChild() {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var newJob = document.createElement("tr");
    newJob.style.backgroundColor=randColor();
    newJob.innerHTML = "<td>Foo "+(i++)+".</td><td>Bar</td>";
    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(newJob);
}


function InsertRow() {
    var indexToInsert=1;
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var newJob = table.tBodies[0].insertRow(indexToInsert);
    newJob.style.backgroundColor=randColor();
    newJob.innerHTML = "<td>Foo "+(i++)+".</td><td>Bar</td>";
}
```

TR is a "table row". TR-elements can be appended only into TABLE, TBODY, THEAD, TFOOT elements.

Find for *appendChild()* and *insertRow()* methods in MDN and MSDN

Comment: Thank you, your code works. Now is there any way to place that new `<tr`> __beneath__ the ID (now called `var under`? I mean, I have multiple table rows and when that function is called, it should be placed beneath table row X.

Comment: Ah, using `nextSibling` works. `table.tBodies[0].insertBefore(newJob,under.nextSibling);`. So thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for this porposes. It's mutch simplier, less code and cross-browser. Here is [examples](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$('<tr>').html('<td>Foo2</td><td>Bar</td>').insertAfter('#row1');
```

Comment: That code actually clears my whole table, and will not append it. But thanks I will look into jQuery then.

Comment: The error is `Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3`

Comment: Why do you think so? in this code you just create new `TR` and then append the innerHtml to the `<td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td>`, and only then you will find the element with id='row1' and append newly created element after the founded element.

Comment: Thank you, this code works indeed. Although my question was for Javascript (and since I'm already working in a already build project) they prefer to use Javascript and not a jQuery library. But I upvoted you none the less.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling insertBefore on the document.body, try calling it on the table:

```
var myTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]; // this is assuming you have just one table

myTable.insertBefore(newJob, under);
```

Also, since you're creating a tr element, don't put the tr in the innerHTML, just put what will go inside it.

Comment: Still `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8`. :(

Answer (score 0):

`var newJob = document.createElement("daps");`

daps is not a valid tag. You're not supposed to pass in the id for the tag you want, but the element, e.g.

```
newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is trying to create a "daps" element (whatever that is). You need to specify the tag name, not an Id or other value. Try this:

```
var newJob = document.createElement("tr");
newJob.innerHTML = "<td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td>";
```

Comment: Still having the `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8` error.

Answer (score 0):

** Edited **
It seems that without hacking it is impossible to add elements to table (makes sense in a way). Therefore you have to use dedicated `insertRow` and `insertCell` functions;

```
function SplitsJob() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var newRow = table.insertRow(0);

    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = "Bar";

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = "Foo";
}
```

Note that in this example new row will be created **at the top** of table and Foo will be **before** Bar

Comment: Still having the `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8` error.

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8` means that the parent element (`document.body`) does not contain the element you are searching for (`under`).

i.e. your `under` element is not directly under the `body` tag.

Try doing -

```
document.body.insertBefore(newJob, newJob.parent);
```

And of course, `innerHTML` should not contain the tag itself! So do -

```
newJob.innerHTML = "<td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a typo? Does it work in other browser then Chrome?

> NOT_FOUND_ERR code 8
>   The referenced node does not exist; for example using insertBefore with a child node that is not a child of the reference node.

See http://observercentral.net/exception8 & http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DOMException

Also, if you just want to add rows to the table, use appendChild() instead of insertBefore().